# AWS CloudFormation stuck at CreateTags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to deploy ECS task. I have managed to do it once, however after deleting cluster and trying to create cluster with all valid names and parameters, I can't manage to do it.

Problem is that my CloudFormation stack is stuck in `ECSService CREATE_IN_PROGRESS`

Googling, I found out I can track exact what is happening using `CloudTrail EventHistory` and I found out I have a problem with `CreateTags`.

It goes `CreateTags` then after some time it does `DeleteNetworkInterface` and then again in circle with `CreateTags` > `DeleteNetworkInterface`.

I have deleted cluster multiple times and created it but to no success. I have deleted ECR and pushed again but nothing works. I have checked out url to my repository image but it is okay.

One thing I noticed is massage you get when creating task `Account settings for Resource Tagging Authorization are currently turned on.

The `ecs:TagResource Action is required to tag ECS resources.`, so I tried adding it to execution role which I also put into `Task Role` when creating Task Definition, but no success.

I have no idea what else to do. I do not get any error (except timeout on CloudFormation Stack).

Anyone have any clue what can I do?

Comment: Did you check the ECS Task traces in your ECS cluster? Maybe the deployment is failing and ECS keeps trying. This happens typically if you turned on the health-check setting and the service is not configured correctly or returns systematically an error.